# Reverting branch in git

Tags: git, merge

I've been working in a branch, say `master`. Changes are already pushed to remote repository. My history looks like this:

```
*----*----*----* master
```

Then I realize that I may have done something wrong and want to start from a different approach. I do this by creating a new branch:

```
*----*----*----* master
     \
      *----*----* different-approach
```

After some new commits, I decide that the new approach works better than the one in the master branch, so I want to use that from now on on the `master` branch. So I do a merge:

```
git checkout master
git merge different-approach
```

In case there is any conflict, I always choose the version from the `different-approach` merge. The problem is that for some files there is no conflict, so git does an automatic merge leaving in the bad stuff from the `master` branch.

What can I do in this case? There seems to be no way to force a manual merge for all files in git. Of course I can clone the repository to a different directory and copy all files from it to the original directory before committing the merge. But isn't there a cleaner and simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix it by reverting unwanted commits.

```
// Revert all commits in master one-by-one
$ git checkout master
$ git revert --no-edit different-approach..master
$ git merge different-approach

// Revert all commits in master at once
$ git checkout master
$ git revert --no-commit different-approach..master
$ git commit -m "Revert foo"
$ git merge different-approach
```

Comment: This might cause a problem if other people pushed changes to master.  Their commits would be reverted as well.

Comment: Well, I expect author is able to run any log viewer to confirm what he reverted.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to completely ignore the changes on `master` not on `different-approach` you can:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard different-approach
```

Warning, this will completely wipe out changes on `master` not on `different-approach`.

Comment: My guess that it won't work if master is already pushed. At least it shouldn't. That's why I need a merge.

Comment: Do you want to change master on remote as well?  If so after the `git reset --hard different-approach` you can `git push -f`.  Warning this does rewrite history on the remote so it seems the previous changes never happened.